# IOS Mapkit or Core Location Solution for Traveling Salesman Problem

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, core-location

Google Directions has an api to solve the [Traveling Salesman Problem](http://the%20shortest%20distance%20that%20touches%20the%20all)--calculate the shortest route on a set of points--but charges for it. In the Apple world, Polyline and MKRoute seem promising but I can't find anything in the documentation to suggest they support more than two points--start and dest. Has anyone had any luck with the TSP problem using MapKit and/or Core Location? It seems one could calculate distance in time for all the edges between nodes using something like:

```
request.source = startLocation
        request.destination = destLocation
        request.requestsAlternateRoutes = true
        request.transportType = .automobile

        let directions = MKDirections(request: request)
        directions.calculate { (directions, error) in

            if var routeResponse = directions?.routes {
                routeResponse.sort(by: {$0.expectedTravelTime <
                    $1.expectedTravelTime})
                let quickestRouteForSegment: MKRoute = routeResponse[0]

                completion(quickestRouteForSegment.expectedTravelTime)  
            }
        }
    }
```

and manually develop an algorithm that tries out the possibilities and selects the fastest.  But this gets complicated quickly and requires many requests. Just wondering if anyone has discovered a more sophisticated way to approach it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to achieve what you want by using Mapkit as you will need a lot of requests and Apple will throttle your app. Stick with Google or Mapbox, they have matrix apis intended for the STP, Mapkit doesn't.

Comment: Also, do you need to install mapbox using carthage or cocoapods?  I would rather not use dependencies if possible.

Comment: You can install it using either, refer to this guide: https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/navigation/overview/installation-and-setup/ Yes Mapbox is solid, it has slightly different model to Google, check which model suits you and go for it.